# Untiunitary operator on a Hilbert space

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators

A bijective linear (antilinear) operator $A$ on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ is called unitary (untiunitrary) if $\langle A\psi |A\phi \rangle =\langle \psi |\phi \rangle$ (resp. $\langle A\psi |A\phi \rangle =\langle \phi |\psi \rangle$) for all $\phi ,\psi \in \mathcal{H}$.

By the relation $\langle \psi |A^{\dagger}\phi \rangle =\langle A\psi |\phi \rangle$, for a unitary operator $A$ we can conclude that $\langle \psi |A^{\dagger}A\phi \rangle =\langle A\psi |A\phi \rangle =\langle \psi |\phi \rangle $ hence $A^{\dagger}A=I$. But how can I get that for an untiunitary operator $U$, we have $U^* U=I$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\ U\ $ is antiunitary, then
\begin{align}
\langle\phi|\psi\rangle&=\langle U\psi|U\phi\rangle\\
&=\overline{\langle\psi|U^*U\phi\rangle}\\
&=\langle U^*U\phi|\psi\rangle
\end{align}
for all $\ \phi,\psi\ .$

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. Why $\langle U\psi |U\psi \rangle =\overline{\langle \psi |U^* U\phi \rangle}$?

Comment: [Definition of $\ U^*\ $ for antilinear $\ U\ $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2257384/adjoint-of-antilinear-operator).

Comment: Sorry I didn't know that. I appreciate your help.